# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (To delete a folder)

Tags: javascript, c#

I have written a file to a specified folder. After writing it to the folder I attach that file to mail. After attaching that file to mail, I want to delete that folder.But folder is not geting deleted and it throws the exception as "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Here is my code.

```
     public HttpResponseMessage SendChannelPartenersMessage(string Name,string FirmName,string Address, string Email,string Mobile)                                        
     {
         var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
         ContactUs contactUs = new ContactUs();
         contactUs.Address = Address;
         contactUs.Name = Name;
         contactUs.FirmName = FirmName;
         contactUs.Email = Email;
         contactUs.Mobile = Mobile;

         try
         {
             if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
             {
                 contactUs.AttachFileName = WriteAttachedFile(httpRequest, contactUs.Email);

                 if (ContactUsService.SendChannelPartenersMessage(contactUs))
                 {
                     var fileToBeDeleted = contactUs.AttachFileName;
                     var deleteFile = DeleteAttachedFile(contactUs.AttachFileName);
                 }
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, contactUs);
             }
             else
             {
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
             }

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
             {
                 Content = new StringContent("An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator."),
                 ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception"
             });
         }
   }

    private string WriteAttachedFile(HttpRequest httpRequest, string FileName)
    {         
        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
        var directoryPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"].ToString() + FileName + "\\\\";
        var filePath = directoryPath + postedFile.FileName;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        var Path = filePath.Replace("\\", "/");
        return (Path);
    }   

     private bool DeleteAttachedFile(string FileName)     
     {
         if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileName))
         {
             System.IO.File.Delete(FileName);
         }

         string[] words = FileName.Split('/');
         string directoryPath = words[words.Length - 2];

         if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
         {
             Directory.Delete(directoryPath);
         }   
         return (true);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the folder that I create for writing is not deleted . Instead it throws an exception :The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the file you sent through the mail is still not being downloaded at the receiver's end. This happens even in sending files through Skype or even copying to USB stick. Make sure the file is downloaded on the receiver's end

Comment: But the user may not download the mail. What how to dispose? whats the solution?

Comment: @user3687566 i believe reciever is not the user who the mail was adressed for. files should be uploaded to the mail server first.

Comment: Physically goto your mail account from which you sent the mail, delete the outgoing mail.

Comment: Yes. I am deleted the folder only after sending the mail successfully.That is after completion of mailing process